# fancy box - lightbox with html content fails in ie, ok in ff

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, fancybox

i installed the fancy box application and works perfectly in ff.
ie 8, in particular has a bunch of problems
i'm on a deadline at work and trying to save my job - can anyone suggest anything??
thanks so much

Comment: What are the errors/issues? You need to post some code..

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to be using javascript prototype instead of DOM.